# How to add an action to a UIButton

Tags: uibutton, action, target

I've been searching online for this answer, and every single post skips over the part of where to actually write the code for an action. I have a simple Interactive UIButton. And If i could just see a template of code that says  "\write code for action here", that would be super helpful!!! ( it's for iPad IOS7 )

This is as far as I can get...

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
   action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

I think I understand that this is how to set up a potential action, but where do I write the actual code for the action itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to kind of expand more on what was answered here already, Both responses are correct but i want to explain why/how this all works.

```
[button addTarget:self  
   action:@selector(aMethod:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

The first thing to look at; The `target`.

The target is the instance of a class, any class. The only requirement for this class is that it has to implement the `action`.

`action` is the method you wish to invoke when the user presses the button.

`@selector(aMethod:)` Basically think of this as a method signature. Because Objective-c is a dynamic language, `aMethod:` does not need to exist, but will crash your program if it does not.

So if we put this all together, Whenever I want to press this button:

The system will invoke the `action` method, on the `target` instance.

and for the method itself, it can look like this

```
- (void) aMethod:(id)sender { }
```

Comment: thanks! thats helpful, do i have to take further steps to declare aMethod as a method? because I am getting the error "undeclared indentifier 'aMethod'"

Comment: No, You do not.
bare in mind that `@selector(aMethod:)` is a completely different method then `@selector(aMethod)` 

if that is indeed the exact copy and paste from your debug console, I would suggest removing `:(id) selector` from your method implementation.

Comment: sorry, I am missing something.. I dont have ":(id) selector" in my code. Im lost on how to fix my "undeclared identifier" problem. thanks in advance! I am new to this

Comment: aha, I got this the wrong way around, My apologies; next time i won't make assumptions like that. So let me understand correctly; You have a method implementation that looks like this: `- (void) aMethod { ... }` but your selector you passed into the `addTarget:action:forControlevents` method looks like this: `@selector(aMethod:)` ?

Comment: thanks for being patient! here is all my code for that button                 `UIButton *plus = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [plus setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    plus.frame = CGRectMake(394, 106, 25, 25);
    [plus setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [objects addSubview:plus];
    plus.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
    
    [plus addTarget:self
    action:@selector(aMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [objects addSubview:plus];- (void) aMethod: (id)sender { }`

Comment: Okay, I see where you went wrong now. Before I answer i will explain the "syntax" (if you will) of `@selector()`, So `@selector` takes a string representation of a method signature i.e.: `aMethod:` The colon on the end designates that your implementation expects a parameter at the end. So, `@selector(aMethod:)` is expecting a method to look like this: `- (void) aMethod:(id) param { ... }` AND `@selector(aMethod)` is expecting a method to look like this: `- (void) aMethod{ ... }`

Comment: Where your `@selector()` looks like this; `@selector(aMethod)` and your implementation looks like this; `- (void) aMethod:(id) sender { }` they are mismatched -- Glad i could help. :)

Comment: Do you mind accepting this as answered, just to help people in the future who also have this problem. Thanks.

Comment: of course! if the green check mark is how to do that, then i just accepted it! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You would put the action related code in a method, in that class, named aMethod:

```
- (void)aMethod:(id)sender {
    // your code for the action goes here
}
```

You perhaps might also want to use UIControlEventTouchUpInside for the control event.

Comment: Thanks! and i borrowed "aMethod" from an online forum thinking it was something that Xcode would recognize. I now know that it is user created, and I understand that a UIbutton calls a method. What exactly does that mean for me? Do I need to create a method elsewhere before calling? can I keep everything within one page of code?

Comment: What it means for you is that, like the answers have said, you need to write your own aMethod implementation in the same .m file, because you have set the target of the UIButton to self (which means "this object instance")

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set the target as self, the aMethod: method should be added to the same class.

```
- (IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender
{
  // do something here
}
```